# How to parse JSON+HAL response into POJO

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Recently I am investigating Spring Boot. I did a simple JPA + DATA + REST spring-boot application. For this initial creation...

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("fname");
    user.setLastName("lname");
    user.setId(1);
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setName("item1");
    item.setPattern("pattern1");
    Item item2 = new Item();
    item2.setName("item2");
    item2.setPattern("pattern2");
    itemRepository.save(item);
    itemRepository.save(item2);
    items.add(item);
    items.add(item2);
    user.setItems(items);
    userRepository.save(user);
```

...the REST interface provides HAL specific responses like this.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/user
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/user{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/user/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "user" : [ {
      "firstName" : "fname",
      "lastName" : "lname",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/user/1"
        },
        "items" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/user/1/items"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Now I want to parse JSON+HAL response to get the User object, but I cannot find a clear example of doing this scenario in java.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not just sending the data in response that you actually want to get? In that case just send back the `User` object and Jackson does rest of that for you.

Comment: My first approach was to return the `User` object and parse it back with ObjectMapper and it worked. But now I am trying to use spring-boot-web with jpa and the default response is json+hal so I am expecting an API to parse it back to `User` again. If this parser doesn't exist than I need a configuration to spring-web to produce simple old json response.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the response from the GET request is. I suppose you want to send POST/UPDATE from front-end or wherever, then you simply just send only the data you need to map. Your http://localhost:8080/user GET can return this json with these wrappers. Now when sending data back to the server, you can only send the object you created or modified.

Comment: Is there a library which can be used for the POST json construction or for the reponse travetsal? A HAL helper java API for ezxample.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. If you want to POST an object to back-end, there is absolutely no point having it in HAL format.

Comment: The code and the json+hal response are at my backend. My fronted is also java (Vaadin) but on a different server. I am looking for a code axample how to retrive a user objet from the backend. Something like: `User user = (User) halJsonObjectMapper.parse( response, User.class);`. Sorry if my question is unclean.

Comment: If you are getting this example json as your POST response then I believe there is no way to simply only get the user, this is collection "_embedded" seems to be what you want to unwrap and only way to map it to User is to have it in some Object that is returned using: `@JsonUnwrapped
Object _embedded;`. Another thing you could look at is `Jackson2HalModule` for `ObjectMapper`